# Virtual Host with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, virtualhost

What if I'm doing an SSL because I need a redirect URI that's https:// so I have this in my xamp apache httpd:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/x/htdocs/project-lara/public"
ServerName fuseuca.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

I also configured the hosts `127.0.0.1 fuseuca.com`

But i still get Web page not available: `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: Turn off your firewall and report back with the results.

Comment: Stop posting this question as an answer to other questions.  Those answers will just be deleted.